# Status triggers and comment triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, integration, case

This is my first time working with Salesforce, and am having trouble finding my way. Hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

I added a new status "Send to Remote" to the "Cases" app in Salesforce.
I am not able to figure out how to achieve the following:

1. Upon changing the status in a case to "Send to Remote", I want to send the following information to a remote server: a) Case owner name, b) Owner email, c) Subject,  d) Description, and e) Case no.
   How do I know when this Status change is triggered, and how do I fetch the above listed data?
2. On creation of each new comment on a case in Salesforce, the comment has to be sent to a remote server along with "Case number". How do I know when this action is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use workflows & outbound messages to implement both of your questions. But before you start working on them I would highly recommend you to read through force.com developer's guide and some workbooks. This will help you figure what exactly needs to be done :)

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

All the Best!